# Do Dynastic Stains go away in Crusader Kings 2: Game of Thrones mod?

Tags: mods, crusader-kings-2

So, it turns out I may have murdered a few too many people and been caught a bit too often. My latest heir has gained the "Dynastic Stain" trait:
[image]

Is this something that is permanent for my dynasty or will it go away after a few generations of being not so prone to plotting?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is a cumulative penalty when you're discovered.  Say you're discovered 3 times, you now have a level 3 'dishonorable' trait (giving -30 to relations, etc). Each new generation lowers it by 1, so your children will start with a -2 Dynastic Stain. If they are discovered on a murder plot it transforms into a -3 dishonorable, or if they are nice and don't murder anyone, their children will have a -1 Dynastic Stain, and if they're also nice, their children will not have it.

Comment: I presume when you say "nice" you actually mean "smart enough to not get caught".